# Find basis and dimension of subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Consider subspace of matrix $X \subset Mat_{n\times n}(F)$:
$A_{i}X+XB_{i} = 0$, where $(A_{i},B_{i})_{i=1}^{m}$ given set of matrix with size $m$.

How can I find dimension of $X$ and their basis? I thought about consider linear combination of some special matrix from $X$ and "delete" some of them to find needed quantity.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: do you have just the two matrices $A_i,B_i$, or do you have several pairs $(A_1,B_1),(A_2,B_2),...$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I fixed it

Comment: The dimension will obviously depends on the matrices. For example, if $A_i = B_i = 0$ for all $i$ then your subspace is $M_n(F)$. If you pick $B_1 = 0, A_1 \in GL_n(F)$ then your subspace is $0$. So there is a big gap and I am afraid there is not much to say unless you have concrete $A_i$ and $B_i$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_i = \{X:A_iX + XB_i = 0\}$. Then your subspace is the intersection
$$
S = \bigcap_{i=1}^n S_i
$$
If you look up an analysis of [Sylvester's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), you can find that $S_i$ is spanned by the matrices of the form $uv^T$ such that for some $\lambda$: $u$ is an eigenvector of $A_i$ associated with $\lambda$, $v$ is an eigenvector of $B_i^T$ associated with $-\lambda$.  Note that this assumes that $F$ is algebraically closed.  I *think* that it's true whether or not $A_i,B_i$ are diagonalizable.

In particular: if you have any pair $A_i,B_i$ such that $A_i$ and $-B_i$ *have no common eigenvalues*, then we will have $S_i = \{0\}$ and therefore $S = \{0\}$.